Fontforge mass glyph alignment
I'm new to FontForge and I struggle to do operations like the following. I suppose that the only possible way is to use a script. Say I have a glyph selection, I'd like to know, for each glyph, what is the lowest point (Y coordinate), and to move the glyph according a delta I give. Here's a specific example:

I select 3 glyphs.
I want all glyphs bottom aligned at Y = 100.
First glyph has its lowest Y a 80, I move it -20.
Second glyph has its lowest Y a 25, I move it -75.
Third glyph has its lowest Y a 110, I move it +10.

Is there way to achieve this? Command line, script, etc.
Thanks.
I searched Stackoverflow for hours. I didn't find anything related.
